# D8 DexMergerTransform: flaky android builds on gitlab-ci

Tags: android, gitlab-ci

Since several days, I see flaky builds on my GitLab CI system.
Sometimes the build fails with this error:

```
Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransform.transform(DexMergerTransform.java:230)
```

When I then retry the build once or twice it works.

I know, this may be difficult to answer, so please add some comments, what I could try or which additional info you would need (unfortunately the project is not open-source): all comments/ideas are welcome.
Here are some thoughts that I have in mind:

1. maybe this is caused by insufficient memory (it's a quite large multi-module build)
2. maybe a timing issue of the build
3. maybe an error in the D8 Dexer

some more info:

- the build is not doing any fancy stuff (android UI tests, etc.).
  It just executes `./gradlew assembleDebug`
- com.android.tools.build:gradle `3.0.1`
- CompileSdkVersion: `26`

Here are some relevant parts of the build-log:

```
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':m10_android_apk:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForRelease'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:213)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)

Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransform.transform(DexMergerTransform.java:230)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:222)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:218)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    ... 116 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ThreadUtils.getExecutorService(ThreadUtils.java:40)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.runForTesting(D8.java:150)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:71)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:73)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:97)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:35)
```